# Creating a rank structure based on score without coding each possibility

Tags: javascript, formula, ranking

I am trying to code a simple rank structure without coding each possibility.

I want ranks 1-10 to be separated by 25 point increments ( 0 points = level 1 though)

Than ranks 11-20 to be separated by 50, 21-30 by 100 etc. Basically increasing the amount between levels by double every 10 levels.

I started with a bunch of if statements, and even tried switch statements but I feel like this is sloppy and a waste of time and code. Any suggestions that can point me into the right direction, so I am not coding every possibility?

I tagged this as javascript because that is what I am coding in, but I am more looking for the general direction/formula and I can figure out the code.

To be clear:

```
0-25 points = Rank 1
26-50 points = Rank 2
51-75 points = Rank 3

etc...

201-225 points = Rank 9
226-250 points = Rank 10

etc....

251-300 = Rank 11
301 - 350 = Rank 12
```

As you can see once ranks 1-10 Have a delta of 25 points between ranks. Ranks 11-20 have a delta of 50 points between ranks, then 21-30 should have 100 point delta between ranks etc.

Also trying to get the remainder, so you know how far you are until next rank.

Comment: Not clear. What exact functionality needs to be implemented?

Comment: I added some more clarifying details, please let me know if that helps

Comment: So, given a number of points you need to determine the rank and remainder?

Comment: Add Ranks 9 and 10 to your sample.

Comment: Added 9 and 10 to the example

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be repeatedly calculating rank (eg. every time someone gains points), with a limited number of possible ranks, simply build a table (array) of total point requirements per rank, using a `for` loop keeping track of rank number, total points needed so far, and points needed to rank up from current rank. So `rankTable[rank] = totalPointsNeededForRank`. Then, whenever someone gains points, you can just check if they've reached the threshold for the next rank by looking up the next rank in the table.

Comment: i dont want a max though

Answer (score 0):

Do it recursive

```
calculate_rank points_left, points_need rank
  tmp_points = points_left - points_need
  rank++
  if tmp_point > 0
    if rank % 10 == 0
      points_need *= points_need
    end
    return calculate_rank tmp_point, points_need, rank
  else
    return rank
  end
end
```

Call the method with the points of the player, 25, 0

Hope it make sense as pseudo code. else I will have to rewrite it